# Value too long for type character varying(255) SQLite3 to Postgres Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have switched from using SQLite3 to Postgres for my Django app.

I have run these commands to get all my data from the SQLite3 database and I wanted to add it to the Postgres database:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > db.json
python manage.py loaddata db.json
```

Then I got this error:

```
Could not load database.Object(pk=XXXXXXXXXX): value too long for type character varying(255)
```

In my `models.py`, the `max_length` is set to 10 and the value of the primary key is 10.

Here is how I set the primary key for that object's model:

```py
models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

Why I am getting that error? I have many other threads about this issue but I haven't yet found an answer that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite uses a form of dynamic typing](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datatypes_in_sqlite) (bold added):

> In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible with the more common static type systems of other database engines in the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases should work the same way in SQLite. **However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.**

One of the "rigid" things it doesn't do is enforce column lengths:

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global [SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.

It sounds like you have some data that doesn't actually fit inside the column types you have defined. Now that you're migrating to PostgreSQL you may have to manually fix some data or adjust your models accordingly.

Try running something like

```sql
select * from app_table order by length(column) desc limit 1;
```

to see what the longest value actually is in that column. Then either extend your model or fix the data.

As an aside, it's not clear if you are migrating your whole workflow to PostgreSQL or just trying to copy data from development to production. I *strongly* urge you to use Postgres in development if that's the database you'll be targeting in production.

The issue you're having now is a great example of how one RDBMS isn't a drop-in replacement for another. You want to find these issues in development, not when you're trying to deploy to production.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful answer! I want to migrate my entire workflow to Postgres. When I ran the command `select length(column) from table_name order by length(column) desc limit 1`, the result was 10 as expected. What do you think the issue is? Does the error mean there is an error with the specific column I checked or is it a problem with one of the other fields? All the other fields' lengths are under 255 chars too...

Comment: The error message references `VARCHAR(255)`, not `VARCHAR(10)`. Are you sure you're looking at the column that's causing the problem?

Comment: Thank you so so much! I found the columns where the problem occurred! Your answer was really helpful! I am definitely going to use Postgres for both development and production! You were extremely helpful!